# Need a clearer explanation how to avoid infinite re-rendering with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Not so fluent with React hooks, used plenty of class components before, hope you'll be forgiving.

The current code causes infinite re-rendering, and I think I understand why - the entire function body is being called on re-render.

```
const NavTabs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState();
  const axiosPromise = getRequest(consts.categoriesURL);

  axiosPromise.then(data => {
    setCategories(data.value);
  })

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
      </AppBar>
      {categories && <DynamicTabs categories={categories}/>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I guess I could do something like `if (!categories) { const axiosPromise [...]` and so forth, i.e. do the http request only if categories haven't been populated yet. I guess this could also be solved by `useEffect`? Or wrapping the hook in an internal function?

I guess my real question is - why is React re-rendering the entire function body? Shouldn't it re-render only the return function? And then what is the point of using hooks that will be re-run on every render?

Compared to class components - shouldn't the code in the function body be equivalent to the constructor code in class components, and the return function - equivalent to the render method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `getRequest` is being invoked each render cycle which sets some state and triggers a rerender. Placing it in an effect hook with a dependency array is likely the best solution. What dependencies you define will dictate when `getRequest` can be invoked.

> Why is React re-rendering the entire function body?

The entire function body needs to run in order to determine the return value.

> And then what is the point of using hooks that will be re-run on every render?

Hooks are run on every render, in the same order they are defined, but depending on dependencies may not invoke a callback. Hooks are what give functional components so much viability and sense of component lifecycle, to nearly be equivalent to class-based components in functionality. In most cases, you can completely convert a class-based component to a functional one and not drop any functionality.

> Compared to class components - shouldn't the code in the function body be equivalent to the constructor code in class components, and the return function - equivalent to the render method?

It is more accurate to think of the entire functional components definition ***as*** the class-based `render` function, which *can* contain some logic and returns computed JSX to render to the DOM.

Example Solution:

```
const NavTabs = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState(); // <-- no initial state!

  useEffect(() => {
    getRequest(consts.categoriesURL).then(data => {
      setCategories(data.value); // <-- will update state and trigger render
    });
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency is run once on component mount

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
      </AppBar>
      {categories && <DynamicTabs categories={categories}/>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I guess I could do something like if (!categories) { const axiosPromise [...] and so forth, i.e. do the http request only if categories haven't been populated yet. I guess this could also be solved by useEffect? Or wrapping the hook in an internal function?

Yes, useEffect is the way to go here. Making a request and setting the result as state are side effects should only be run once in your case. We can achieve that easily with useEffect.

> I guess my real question is - why is React re-rendering the entire function body? Shouldn't it re-render only the return function? And then what is the point of using hooks that will be re-run on every render?

React has no way to split a js function and only re-render the return.  The function is atomic and must be completed. That is what hooks are for. React controls when hooks are ran so it can do fun stuff like batch state updates, ignore outdated effects and prioritise high priority work like animations.

> Compared to class components - shouldn't the code in the function body be equivalent to the constructor code in class components, and the return function - equivalent to the render method?

The functional component is equivalent to the render method of a class component. They are called in a similar way. All the other lifecycle methods are replaced by hooks.

I recommend the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) are great place to start and Dan Abramov has a [great deep dive on hooks](https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/).

Answer (score 1):

To answer "why react is running the entire function" the answer is that javascript functions work that way: you always have to run the whole thing, they don't stop in the middle*. I understand what you are thinking here, if you are used to class components: don't I have a constructor section and a render section? and the answer is: not really if you are using function components. You only have render. But hooks are magic, and they let you pretend to have two parts.

Hooks know when they are called, and assuming you always call them in the same order, the can keep track of state outside the render function. so the way the work is sorta like this:

1. React detects a function component and creates or re-uses an existing rendering context for that component. This is where the hook information lives.
2. React calls your function component and it starts running.
3. You call hooks within your function component. These check what the current rendering context is, and save/get relevant information from that context. In a sense the rendering context is a "global" variable.
4. You do whatever else you want within the function, and eventually return a component tree (JSX) or null.
5. react then (eventually) updates the DOM to match what you returned, and saves the changes to the rendering context, so the next time render is called, it can re-use the context.

The magic is that the rendering context can do fancy things with hooks, like only run them once, always return the same value from a hook, or any other number of things. But in a sense, the component "class" becomes the react-internal rendering context that hooks know how to access.

Here is an example of the `useState` hook implemented in a class component: (You wouldn't ever need to do this, but it's an example of how hooks work).

```js
class FakeHook extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args)
    this.state = {}
    this.useStateCalls = 0
  }
  
  useState(defaultValue){
    const currentRenderContext = this.state
    let value = defaultValue
    const currentStateKey = `useState${this.useStateCalls}`
    if (currentStateKey in currentRenderContext) value = currentRenderContext[currentStateKey]
    this.useStateCalls++
    
    return[value, (newValue) => this.setState({[currentStateKey]: newValue})]
  }
  
  render(){
    this.useStateCalls = 0
    let [fooState, setFoo] = this.useState("foo default")
    let [barState, setBar] = this.useState("bar default")
    
    return(
      <dl>
        <dt>Foo state</dt>
        <dd>
          <strong>Value:</strong>
          <div>{fooState}</div>
          <button onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); setFoo(`foo updated at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`)}}>Update Foo</button>
        </dd>
        <dt>Bar state</dt>
        <dd>
          <strong>Value:</strong>
          <div>{barState}</div>
          <button onClick={(event) => {event.preventDefault(); setBar(`bar updated at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`)}}>Update Bar</button>
        </dd>
        <dt>Render context state:</dt>
        <dd><pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre></dd>
      </dl>
    )
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<FakeHook/>, document.getElementById('main'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main id=main>loading or error occurred...</main>
```

Notice that state is stored based on the order the hook is called inside render. In real hooks, the render context is stored somewhere other than `this.state`, but hooks know how to get it, and you don't really care. Also, this is just an example, real hooks work slightly differently, but the concept is the same.

*: `async` functions and generators don't run all at once, and instead return a special object that lets the function run in multiple steps, waiting or pausing on `await` or `yield`.